# Putty - Command Line Prefixes?

Tags: git, ssh, putty

Im using putty to connect to my servers via ssh and use .git to pull all the files that I need from my git repo. The problem I have though is my hosting provider only allow me to use "/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git COMMAND" to use git instead of a simple "git COMMAND", this becomes very stressful and annoying because i usually forget to add the path and have to type it all again.

My question is, is there any way to shorten the way that i access my git commands? Perhaps something that recognises that when i type "git" it needs to look for git in the path "/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/" and then git. I hope its clear what im asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create symlinks in your hosting provider, then this would be one way to avoid having to type out the full path each time.  Something like this should work:

```
ln -s /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git my_git
```

This would create a symlink to your Git installation called `my_git`, wherever you run the above command.

To run the symlink, just use:

```
./my_git
```

from the location of the actual symlink.